# python asyncio.gather use input as part of return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a function something like

```
async def funcn(input: input_type) -> output_type:
  ....
  return output
```

I am calling it using asyncio.gather like:

```
output = await asyncio.gather(*[funcn(input) for input in input_list])
```

Here return value will be List of output for each input in the input_list.

But I want the return value to be something like [(input, output)] for each input in input_list. Is it possible somehow without changing the implementation of the function ?

Comment: return tuple like `return (input, ouput)`

Comment: @l.b.vasoya I can't change the function implementation code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of `asyncio.gather` will be returned in the same order as the input, so you just need to zip your `input_list` with `output`:

```
for input_value, output_value in zip(input_list, output):
    print(input_value, output_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `zip` from deceze's answer, you could always *wrap* `funcn` with another function that returns the input and the output. That allows you to decorate the output without modifying the processing function:

```
async def wrap_funcn(input):
    output = await funcn(input)
    return input, output

...
ins_and_outs = await asyncio.gather(*[wrap_funcn(input) for input in input_list])
```

This can be useful in case `input_list` is an iterator whose contents is spent after the call to `gather()` which exhausts it.